# invoking JIRA web service from PL/SQL

Tags: web-services, plsql, oracle11g

Business need is to get JIRA issues into oracle database Using RESTful webservice.
Tried connecting using utl_http but failed to pass the username and password.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide CONCRETE details - code, error messages, etc.

Comment: I am looking forward to get a way to accomplish this job.no error messages.I am still not able to get a way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utl_http.set_authentication` to set basic authentication method

```
DECLARE
    v_url                          VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR) := 'http://jira_host/rest/api/2/issue/MKEY-1';
    v_http_req                     utl_http.req;
    v_http_resp                    utl_http.resp;
    v_response                     VARCHAR2(32000 CHAR);
    v_response_clob                CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_http_req := utl_http.begin_request (v_url, 'GET', 'HTTP/1.1');

    -- Set Headers
    UTL_HTTP.set_body_charset(v_http_req, 'UTF-8');
    -- Set authentication
    utl_http.set_authentication(v_http_req, username => 'user', password => 'password');

    -- Send request
    v_http_resp := utl_http.get_response(v_http_req);

    -- Read response
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_text(v_http_resp, v_response, 10000);
            dbms_Output.put_line(v_response);
            v_response_clob := v_response_clob || v_response;
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
            NULL;
    END;

    -- Close connection
    utl_http.end_response (v_http_resp);
END;
/
```